# High Vulnerabilities with postcss in react project

Tags: reactjs, react-admin, postcss

I have this react admin based project (TS) and I noticed that I have a bunch of vulnerabilities, all spinning around postcss. I tried to add the latest version in package.json, resolutions more precisely, but I end up with the same issues (different format of the message).

Here it goes:
postcss-modules-values: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:

```
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-modules-local-by-default: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
modules-extract-imports: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-modules-scope: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-import-parser: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-icss-parser: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-url-parser: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-flexbugs-fixes: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
autoprefixer: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-attribute-case-insensitive: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
css-blank-pseudo: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-color-functional-notation: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-color-gray: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-color-hex-alpha: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-color-mod-function: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-color-rebeccapurple: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-custom-media: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-custom-properties: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-custom-selectors: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-dir-pseudo-class: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-double-position-gradients: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-env-fn: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-focus-visible: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-focus-within: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-font-variant: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-gap-properties: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
css-has-pseudo: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-image-set-function: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-initial: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-lab-function: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-logical-properties: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-media-minmax: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-nesting: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-overflow-shorthand: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-page-break: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-place: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-prefers-color-scheme: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-pseudo-class-any-link: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-replace-overflow-wrap: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-selector-matches: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-selector-not: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-system-ui-font: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
postcss-preset-env: postcss.plugin was deprecated. Migration guide:
https://evilmartians.com/chronicles/postcss-8-plugin-migration
```

And a sneak peak of my package json

```
{
  "name": "admin-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^2.12.1",
    "@azure/msal-react": "^1.0.0-beta.0",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.58",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.7.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.20",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^16.14.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.11",
    "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.8",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "country-region-data": "^1.7.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "immer": "^8.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^3.13.4",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-admin": "^3.13.4",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.15.4",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.0",
    "ssri": "^8.0.1",
    "ts-money": "^0.4.6",
    "typescript": "^3.9.9",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "build:dev": "env-cmd -f .env.dev npm run build",
    "build:stage": "env-cmd -f .env.stage npm run build",
    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f .env.prod npm run build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "immer": "^8.0.1",
    "ssri": "^8.0.1",
    "marked": "^2.0.0",
    "hosted-git-info": "^4.0.2",
    "sanitize-html": "^2.3.3",
    "underscore": "^1.13.1"
  }
}
```

How can I possibly solve them? I gotta deploy.

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

React-admin doesn't use postcss, it's a dependency added by create-react-app. Upgrade the react-scripts package to get rid of these alerts.

Comment: I did so, and I still get these 80 vulnerabilities. If I try to run 'npm audit fix', they require "manual review"